# awk not working on piped output from sed

Tags: awk, sed, zsh, pipe

I have a log file which roughly looks like this:

```
Sep 23 10:28:26 node kernel: em0: device is going DOWN
Sep 23 10:28:26 node kernel: em0: device is going UP
Sep 23 10:29:14 node cdsmon: /tmp/instance0 ; core dumped
Sep 23 10:29:14 node cdsmon: /tmp/instance0 ; core dumped
Sep 23 10:28:26 node kernel: em0: device is going DOWN
Sep 23 10:29:14 node cdsmon: /tmp/instance1 ; core dumped
Sep 23 10:28:26 node kernel: em0: device is going UP
Sep 23 10:29:14 node cdsmon: /tmp/instance2 ; core dumped
```

I want to detect the lines with `cdsmon` and then split the line by `;` (to get the `/tmp/instance0` and the event like `core dumped`).

For this I used `sed` as:

```
sed -u -n -e "s/^.*cdsmon: //p" /tmp/dev.log
```

which gives output as:

```
/tmp/instance0 ; core dumped
/tmp/instance0 ; core dumped
/tmp/instance1 ; core dumped
/tmp/instance2 ; core dumped
```

But upon piping this output to `awk` as shown below, it gives the same output as above:

```
sed -u -n -e "s/^.*cdsmon: //p" /tmp/dev.log | awk -F ";" "{print $1}"
```

The same is observed despite removing the `-u` option from `sed`.

Can anyone please point out if I'm missing anything? I'm using a FreeBSD box with regular awk/sed and unfortunately cannot install any new package.

Comment: You never need sed when you're using awk. Any time you find yourself piping any combination of sed, grep, and/or awk to each other you can be sure you could do the whole thing with just awk.

Comment: @EdMorton: In most cases, sure. But that can't beat sed oneliners.

Comment: @s.ouchene if you have sed piped to grep, etc. as I described then it's not a sed oneliner. Also, in my 40+ years of experience using sed and as one of the top answerers of sed questions on SO (see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sed/topusers), in many cases other than a simple `s/old/new/` with no variables in the search or replacement sections you can easily beat a sed oneliner for robustness, portability, efficiency, clarity, etc. so YMMV.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The reason for the behavior of `awk` is that you have enclosed the program in *double* quotes, which leaves the string open to variable expansion by the shell. That means the shell from which you are running the program will first expand `$1`, and since that is likely undefined, it expands to the empty string.

So, your program amounts to

```
awk -F ";" "{print}"
```

and this is why the entire line is printed. This is one of the reasons you should always include your `awk` (and `sed`) programs in *single* quotes.

Note that in most cases you don't need to pipe the output from `sed` into `awk` or vice versa. In your example, if you want to get the first field after the "event label", you could do the following:

```
sed -E -n 's/^.*cdsmon: ([^;]*).*$/\1/p' /tmp/dev.log
```

This will define a *capture group* around the string after `cdsmon:` and up to the first `;`, and replace the entire line with the content of that capture group.

If you want to print a summary of the events logged by `cdsmon`, you can expand the `sed` approach above as:

```
sed -E -n 's/^.*cdsmon: ([^;]*) ; (.*)$/\1 : \2/p' dev.log
```

Alternatively, here is another `awk`-only approach:

```
awk -F'(cdsmon: | ; )' 'NF==3{printf "%s : %s\n",$2,$3}' dev.log
```

For your example, both will print

```
/tmp/instance0 : core dumped
/tmp/instance0 : core dumped
/tmp/instance1 : core dumped
/tmp/instance2 : core dumped
```

but be aware that the `awk` approach can stumble on edge cases. It takes the patterns `cdsmon:`  and `;` as field separators. When there are three fields (in your example, it can only happen for the `cdsmon:` entries), it prints the second and third field, corresponding to the instance name after `cdsmon:` and the reason after `;`.

Answer (score 8):

[According to the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Quoting.html):

> Double quotes protect most things between the opening and closing
> quotes. The shell does at least variable and command substitution on
> the quoted text. Different shells may do additional kinds of
> processing on double-quoted text.
>
> Because certain characters within double-quoted text are processed by
> the shell, they must be escaped within the text. Of note are the
> characters ‘$’, ‘`’, ‘\’, and ‘"’, all of which must be preceded by a
> backslash within double-quoted text if they are to be passed on
> literally to the program.

So in your case you can escape the dollar sign `$`:

```
sed -u -n -e "s/^.*cdsmon: //p" /tmp/dev.log | awk -F ";" "{print \$1}"
```

But is easier just to use single quotes:

```
sed -u -n -e "s/^.*cdsmon: //p" /tmp/dev.log | awk -F ' ; ' '{ print $1 }'
```

Also you can leave spaces between the separator `' ; '` so you won't end with an invisible space after each line.

You can also just use `awk`:

```bsh
$ awk -F': | ; ' '/cdsmon/ { print $2 }' /tmp/dev.log
/tmp/instance0
/tmp/instance0
/tmp/instance1
/tmp/instance2
```

Comment: Thank you! I was using `zsh` and it was still treating `$1` as an input, this suggestion helps.

Answer (score 8):

I'd use `awk` for the entire operation. Here, I'm splitting on colons, so after the date/time has been considered, the host matching must be applied to the third field (`14 node cdsmon` for example):

```
awk -F: '
    $3 ~ / cdsmon$/ {
        split($4, text, / *; */);    # Split field at semicolon
        sub(/^ */, "", text[1]);     # Remove leading space
        printf "instance %s, reason %s\n", text[1], text[2]
    }
' /tmp/dev.log
```

Here is an alternate and simpler solution that was suggested in a [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/670284/awk-not-working-on-piped-output-from-sed/670289?noredirect=1#comment1263748_670289), where we split on either colon or semicolon so the necessary fields are already directly in `awk` variables:

```
awk -F': | *; *' '
    $1 ~ / cdsmon$/ { printf "instance %s, reason %s\n", $2, $3 }
' /tmp/dev.log
```

You didn't say how you wanted to extract the instance and reason (or if you did, I missed it), so I've just printed them out in a string, demonstrating that they have been correctly extracted.

Comment: Thank you for this `awk` only example. Splitting by `:` might not be reliable for my case. I believe using `/cdsmon/` and rest of your program will help.

Comment: Isn't it easier to use `-F': | ; '` as field separator?

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity that could work too. I tend to forget that `FS` can be a multicharacter ERE

Comment: Could even use ```' cdsmon: '``` as  a separator (discard any line that doesn't split).

Comment: @TobySpeight there are lots of possibilities. I think that one would end up with me having to revert to the complexity of the first option

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~ /cdsmon/){print $(i+1),$(i+3),$(i+4)}}}' filename
```

output

```
/tmp/instance0 core dumped
/tmp/instance0 core dumped
/tmp/instance1 core dumped
/tmp/instance2 core dumped





awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~ /cdsmon/){print $(i+1)}}}' filename
/tmp/instance0
/tmp/instance0
/tmp/instance1
/tmp/instance2
```

Comment: Please note that your first approach only works if the "reason" part of the cdsmon log message consists of exactly two words.